# Find out the sum of values based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have following MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `mileage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `dt` date default NULL,
  `vehicle` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `qty` double default NULL,
  `km` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `mileage` (`id`, `dt`, `vehicle`, `qty`, `km`, `status`) VALUES 
(1, '2016-03-01', 'CA1234', 100, 2030, 'Full'),
(2, '2016-03-02', 'CA1234', 50, 2300, 'Not-Full'),
(3, '2016-03-02', 'CA1234', 25, 2650, 'Not-Full'),
(4, '2016-03-03', 'CA1234', 70, 3010, 'Not-Full'),
(5, '2016-03-06', 'CA1234', 100, 3550, 'Full'),
(6, '2016-03-07', 'CA1234', 60, 3800, 'Not-Full'),
(7, '2016-03-08', 'CA1234', 40, 4000, 'Not-Full'),
(8, '2016-03-09', 'CA1234', 35, 4200, 'Full'),
(9, '2016-03-11', 'CA1234', 40, 4400, 'Not-Full');
```

I am new to MySQL. I want the result to look like this.  I searched many tutorials online but I can't get the result I am looking for

```
Sno Date    Vehicle Fuel Qty    Kilometer Reading   Tank Status Distance    Tank Full Distance  Tank Full Fuel Qty  Mileage
1   2016-03-01  CA1234  100 2030    Full    0   0   0   0
2   2016-03-02  CA1234  50  2300    Not-Full    270 0   0   0
3   2016-03-02  CA1234  25  2650    Not-Full    350 0   0   0
4   2016-03-03  CA1234  70  3010    Not-Full    360 0   0   0
5   2016-03-06  CA1234  100 3550    Full    540 1520    245 6.204081633
6   2016-03-07  CA1234  60  3800    Not-Full    250 0   0   0
7   2016-03-08  CA1234  40  4000    Not-Full    200 0   0   0
8   2016-03-09  CA1234  35  4200    Full    200 650 135 4.814814815
9   2016-03-11  CA1234  40  4400    Not-Full    200 0   0   0
```

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6zyM.png)

I tried

```
    SELECT @row_num := @row_num +1 AS SNo,X.vehicle as VehicleNo,
    X.dt as Date,
    X.qty as Quantity,X.status AS TankStatus,
    X.km as KilometerReading,if( @lastSN = DATE_FORMAT(X.dt,    '%Y-%m-%d'), 
    X.km - @lastValue, 0000 ) as Distance,
    @lastSN := DATE_FORMAT(X.dt, '%Y-%m-%d') AS A,
    @lastValue := X.km AS B FROM (

    SELECT id ,dt ,vehicle ,qty ,km ,status from mileage 

    )X , 
    ( select @lastSN := 0, @lastValue := 0, @row_num :=0 ) SQLVars order  by X.dt
```

Comment: You're expecting someone to be able to drive several quintillion km in their vehicle? Not sure a `BIGINT` is necessary here.

Comment: Please **stop** flagging this post for moderator attention, and asking for help. The "in need of moderator attention" flag is for serious issues; not for you to demand help.